# Install X Server on ubuntu-server 16.04 for comparepdf

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, graphical-user-interface

I'm using [comparepdf](https://www.qtrac.eu/comparepdf.html) (installed from ubuntu apt) to run automated tests which works fine on my desktop, but not on the server, the error returned is:

```
comparepdf: cannot connect to X server
```

This surprised me as I assumed comparepdf is a CLI tool, it doesn't have a GUI. But perhaps in the background it renders PDFs for comparison, for which it needs a GUI.

So what is the most minimal package I can install that might satisfy comparepdf?

Comment: SOLVED: Using xvfb (virtual x-server) as per [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64820/wkhtmltopdf-wkhtmltoimage-cannot-connect-to-x-server) worked

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: SOLVED: Using xvfb (virtual x-server) as per below worked http://askubuntu.com/questions/64820/wkhtmltopdf-wkhtmltoimage-cannot-connect-to-x-server

Comment: trivial answer converted to comment??

Comment: :) Yeah you can answer your question.